# Get user favorite post thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, post

This code "the_user_favorites_list($user_id, $site_id, $include_links, $filters, $include_button);" displays post title. How can I get the post thumbnail?

Answer (score 0):

[get_user_favorites()](https://favoriteposts.com/) just returns the post ids in an array.  If you pass those ids to get_the_post_thumbnail() you will get the html for image tag that uses the image thumbnail as it's src attribute.  For example:

```
$array_of_post_ids = get_user_favorites($user_id, $site_id, $include_links, $filters, $include_button);
foreach ($array_of_post_ids as $post_id){
     echo '<div class="post-thumbnail-' . $post_id .'">;
     echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id);
     echo '</div>';
}
```